# TiKz/PS Blending at the pixel level

Tags: tikz-pgf

To do proper blending easily in TiKz, I need to do be able to have a special blend mode. (this is relevant to anything dealing with graphics and not tiks/tex)

- When you plot a pixel with an alpha channel the graphics package or graphics card will mix the pixel color below it with the new one. eg., suppose we have (100,0,0,255) and we plot (50,50,0,50) on top of it. The new pixel will be (100*(255 - 50)/255 + 50*50/255, 50*50/255, 0, 255) = (80, 10, 0, 255).
- Now when you have a white background you always end up mixing with white for the initial pixel. So if you plot any pixel for the first time with an alpha channel it will get blended with white and become washed out. (255, 255, 255, 255) blended with (255, 0, 0, 50) = (255, 205, 205, 255)
- This is the default behavior of tikz and most graphics packages that plot with alpha channel(you just mix pixels)
- I would like, instead, to plot where the first color does not mix. Basically if it is the first pixel to be plotted then it's alpha channel will always be set to 255. This prevents colors from being washed out and allows for complex geometrical conditions that break others.
- Anyone know if TiKz can do this or be modified to do it? Basically one has to keep a bit buffer where each bit represents if a pixel has been plotted for the first time or not(sort of a like a z-buffer). Blending mode - This mode is basically "Set Alpha channel to 255 for new pixels"
- One can do the test on the primitive level in tikz BUT this does not get partial overlapped objects. Think of two circles that overlap but not totally. One circle is "new"(in the sense that all pixels are new) and the other is partially new(some pixels, the overlapped ones) are not new while the others are. Using tikz's fill opacity cannot handle this case(although you could do some clipping and stuff that becomes very complex quickly).

One way to see this at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/

notice the last diagram and how washed out all the colors are. In my mode they will not be washed out because none of the circles pixels will be blended with white but all blend with themselves.

Again, one can achieve my effect in a very complex manner by using clipping and changing alpha values but it can be achieved much easier given the method I have described = if new pixel then force alpha channel = 255.

Comment: Why do you think that things get complex quickly? Please check the `transparency group` in the manual. Besides, can you put very simple examples that shows what you wanted. Because I don't follow what is new and what is not? Can you please rephrase in terms of layer top-bottom analogy? Also in the last example there is an opacity setting in effect.

Comment: @percusse Did you read what I said? Did you go to the venn diagram example? Can you reproduce that(without washout describe in my post) easily wish transparency groups without using clipping? I see nothing about transparency groups that work from the examples given at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pgf-version-2/

Comment: If you are having trouble thinking about what I am saying then just think of pixels. This is a pixel issue, and alpha blending issue and has nothing to do with higher level objects(except insomuch as they are made up of pixels). Do you understand why normal alpha blending at the pixel level produces "washout" if not then please work on that first as that is where the problem comes from.

Comment: BTW, I'm not saying TiKz can't do it already but I haven't found anything about it.

Comment: I'm just saying that I didn't understand. Probably others could. But I do think that instead of writing up a question about graphics, giving actual images would help much better in understanding the question

Comment: Your last assumption is false ("I imagine TikZ does all the blending").  TikZ does nothing in this regard: it is all passed on to the output format.  If you can figure out a way to do this in the PDF specification, then it might be possible to get TikZ to output the correct parameters.  What you are asking for (as far as I can understand) is that the graphics system use the alpha channel for constructing the picture and then throw that away when placing the picture on the page.  But this isn't what happens: each element is placed on the page individually.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Your idea is wrong in that it will not result in the correct output. You must set the alpha of the first pixel to 1 no matter what. If you don't the pixel will be different when blended with the second pixel. If TiKs doesn't work at the pixel level but there is some point where it can be done then it is easy to do. I do not know enough about the TeX rendering pipeline to know where to look for the pixel rendering part.

Comment: Right, but my main point is that this is handled by the *renderer* (usually PDF, but not necessary) and so is out of the control of TeX.  TikZ does *not* work at the pixel level.  The thing that does pixels is the program that actually displays the picture on your screen, or prints it out.  PDF is a vector format so TeX cannot know what actually corresponds to a pixel.  Therefore, what you ask for cannot be done in the method that you prescribe.  It may be possible to achieve the *effect* by some means, would that be good enough?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Well, if there is no way to get access to the renderer and add these features then pass them along to tikz it is impossible to do in a way that will be most general. I have already implemented what I needed and it will work for my specific case. I'll update my post to try and reflect that it is not just tikz that needs to be able to handle this so that someone else might know how to do this.

Comment: I assume by the pdf vector format, what you mean, is that tiks uses a higher level "api" for graphics sort of like using opengl or direct3d? Even if one can plot single pixels, there is probably no way to modify, at the pixel level, the higher level commands? With 3d graphics one now has "shaders" which lets one work at the pixel level and it would be quite easy to apply the effect I'm talking about(well, except it require significant memory and I'm not sure if shaders can handle that).

Comment: I guess the "ps/pdf viewer" is the thing that interprets the commmands and would be required to have the ability to render. So, even if you implemented some feature like this the "render"(the ps/pdf viewers) probably won't display it? So it seems there is actually very little hope in this case unless some tricks could be used. (I was thinking of possibly using a global clip mask that is updated each time something is added and it basically clips out all old pixels... probably slow but possible and might be just as general)

Comment: I've converted my comments to an "answer" of a sorts, and put in one "trick" that could be used to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible because the output formats do not implement it.  The most common output formats for TikZ/PGF are **vector** formats.  This means that they do not specify graphic elements by pixels but by paths, with instructions on what to do with those paths.  This has definite advantages in that they are typically smaller (admittedly, for types of drawing particularly suited to this format) and they scale perfectly.  It is the job of the *renderer* or *viewer* to interpret these commands into something on the screen or paper and it is only at that stage where pixels come into play.  By this point, TeX is out of play and it is not possible to feed back information from the renderer to the original tex process.

For more on what a vector format is, take a look at the [Wikipedia page on PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Vector_graphics).

However, that's not to say that what you ask for is *impossible*.  It is certainly possible to simulate the effect that you want.  The most straightforward way that I can think of is the following: you want the "base" colour at each point to be the colour that is first drawn there.  So we start by creating a copy of the picture where each colour is its initial colour.  Then we draw the real picture on top of this with the alphas as desired.  This should have the correct effect since when each element gets rendered then if it is "first" it will get blended with an opaque copy of itself, whence be the opaque version of itself, but if it is not first then it blends with what's already there as it ought to.

To create the copy where each colour is its initial colour then we draw the image in reverse with each colour set to fully opaque.  This might take a little planning for a particular picture, of course.

Here's the example of the Venn diagram that you linked to.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48905/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(45:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1]
        \fill[red] \firstcircle;
        \fill[green] \secondcircle;
        \fill[blue] \thirdcircle;
        \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$A$};
        \draw \secondcircle node [above] {$B$};
        \draw \thirdcircle node [below] {$C$};
    \end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
        \fill[blue] \thirdcircle;
        \fill[green] \secondcircle;
        \fill[red] \firstcircle;
\begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1,every node/.style={ellipse,fill=white}]
        \fill[red] \firstcircle;
        \fill[green] \secondcircle;
        \fill[blue] \thirdcircle;
        \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$A$};
        \draw \secondcircle node [above] {$B$};
        \draw \thirdcircle node [below] {$C$};
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result (original on top):

[image: fading with opacity for first colour down]

Comment: The 2nd case is very close but I am not sure if it is is truely the same. It may work though but does require one to keep a "history" of all the objects and I'm not sure if more complex geometrical configurations would work. I'll have to think about it some more but SamB's adobe link does have some compositing/blending stuff about pdf's at the pixel level so it might be possible to do what I want.

Comment: My second case is exactly what you describe.  I've taken a look at the link in Sam's post.  You cannot do what you want from the formula in Section 3: there is no way to adjust the numbers to get what you describe.  So my statement about this not being supported stands.  However, it does show that you can do more interesting things that I thought possible and not all of those are realised in TikZ (yet).

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand the precise details of what you're looking for, but I suspect that you would find these links informative:

- [Ghostcript's Transparency operators](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Language.htm#Transparency)
- [Adobe Technical Note #5407, "Transparency in PDF"](http://web.archive.org/web/20011109072226/http://partners.adobe.com/asn/developer/acrosdk/docs/PDF_Transparency.pdf)

Comment: In the adobe version, section 3 they have the computation for blending they use. I am not sure if my formula will work or not as I just glanced over it(got other things to do ATM). The question is, pdf's seem to support it but how difficult would it be to get into tikz?

Comment: That second document was a very interesting read about PDF and transparency.  Nice sleuth work.