# tikz dim all colors

Tags: tikz-pgf

In tikz, is there a way using a scope environment of some form to "dim" a group of elements?

By "dim", I mean that for every color (be it stroke, fill, or font):

```
I want the color (R,G,B)!x to be mapped to (R,G,B)!(x/2)
```

Concrete examples:

```
black!100 => black!50;
blue!100 => blue!50;
blue!60 => blue!30;
```

Please let me know if there is anyway I can improve this question to meet standards.

Comment: I don't think "dimming" is the right word here, since that implies darkening the colours, while your mapping actually describes lightening them.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it better. (I'm a tikz newb and don't have the right terminology.) The word "dim" came from the fact that as opacity decreases, it's "harder to see", but I agree, from a purely RGB perspective, it is "getting brighter."

Comment: It's good that you want to share the things you find out by posting questions and answering them yourself, but it's typically considered nicer to give other people a bit of time to write answers before posting your own. You might want to take a look at [Asking a question and answering it yourself straight away](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away?lq=1) for a bit of discussion on this.

Comment: Jake: I'm not familiar with the customs here, so please advise me on how to best fit in. My current work flow is something like this: 1) run into tikz problem, 2) google 3) if no obvious answer, post to tex.stackexchange 4) go back to googling -- then, if after more digging, I find that my question is trivially answered by another question, I write up my own answer.

Comment: For none of these questions, do I know the answer before hand. So I think my options are: 1) delete the question [which might be bad if others google the same terms as I do], 2) leave the question unanswered [which might be a bit rude if the question is easily answered by "RTFM"-ing another post], or 3) ... I'm not sure how else to handle this.

Comment: That's a good approach, and you definitely shouldn't delete your questions. What I would recommend, though, (but that's just my personal opinion) is to wait a bit longer (couple of hours) before posting a self-answer, especially if it's a very short answer. Questions (especially regarding TikZ) don't typically go unanswered, and you stand a good chance of getting quite detailed explanatory answers, but those chances are reduced if there's already a self-answer, because it can give off the impression that the asker isn't actually interested in an answer from someone else.

Comment: Jake: understood. Thanks for explaining the dynamics of tex.stackexchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the `xxcolor` package? It is distributed as part of `PGF`. See "Extended Color Support" in the 2.10 `PGF` manual. It works outside pictures (i.e., on text) as well, but also applies inside pictures. Note that in this example the `colormixin` environment is outside the `tikzpicture`, but does not have to be.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xxcolor}
\begin{document}

\foreach \mixin in {, 25!white, 25!black, 25!orange}{
    \begin{colormixin}{\mixin}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill [red] rectangle (1,1);
            \fill [green] (0,1) circle [radius=0.5];
            \draw [blue] (0,0) -- (1, 1);
            \node [below] {\strut\mixin};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{colormixin}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mark: very nice! Now I see what Jake meant by 'learn from other answers.' Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 7):

Use the following.

```
\begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.5, draw opacity=0.5, text opacity=0.5]
... your existing tikz commands
\end{scope}
```

See [TiKz/PS Blending at the pixel level](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48905/tikz-ps-blending-at-the-pixel-level) for more details.